# Windows 2012 as DNS server always replies two timed out request before giving the IP address

Tags: dns, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a DNS server running under **Windows 2012 Server R2** (**WS2012R2**) but every time I "ask" for a name resolution it ALWAYS replies with 2 `DNS request timed out` message first and then gives me the IPv4 address. I mean every single time. The thing is I am connected to the server using a single Point-to-point UTP wire connection. Also there is no forwarders declared and the server is using itself as the preferred DNS server (tested with `127.0.0.1` and `172.16.1.1`). I should say every single time I used **WS2012R2** and **WS2012** as DNS Server this happened to me.

I'm going to post here below some captures to describe better the problem:

1- Querying the DNS server for itself (`nslookup pdc.domain.my`)

[image: CMD capture]

2- Checking for forwarders in configuration

[image: No forwarders defined]

3- Checking server's IPv4 address under testing purposes

[image: IP address config with 172.16.1.1]

4- Checking the IP addresses the server is listening on

[image: Listening interfaces]

Comment: Is the server actually responding with that, or is the client coming up with that message because the server is too slow in responding?

Comment: What addresses is the DNS server configured to listen on? Any query sent to an address that it is not listening on will cause a response like that.

Comment: The server is responding for it. The nslookup query is from a client computer in the subnet 172.16.1.0/24 asking for the name pdc.domain.my to the server itself. Could be for instance freenas.domain.my and the server will reply two request timed out first and then the IP address.

Comment: Just added the Interfaces from the server is listening to. Only IPv4 is listening, IPv6 is unchecked.

Comment: Do you get the same result if you perform the lookups directly on the server itself?

Comment: Did it now and yes, I got the same result. Basically that is not a serious problem because on third try it gives me the address. But still I guess that's not the proper behavior.